# c# instantiate the list of enum in an interface correctly

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a xunit test that will create a instance of the CalculateDistanceService so that i can call it without using mock and i am having difficult writing it. I do not know how to instantiate the  _operators correctly to return enum values.
The issue that i am facing when i can not create the CalculateDistance class to have enums populate for the test. When i call the class the enum values are empty and i am not sure how to do this correctly.

```
    public CalculateDistanceService()
    {
       _operators = operators;
    }

    public interface ICalculateDistance<out T> where T: Enum
    {
        T DistanceMethod { get; }
        DistanceResponse CalculateDistance(DistancePoint point1, DistancePoint point2, MeasureUnit measureUnit);
    }

    public enum DistanceMethod
    {
        GeodesicCurve,
        Pythagoras
    }
```

What I have tried to do in the unit test

```
    public DistanceControllerTest()
    {
       _operators = new List<ICalculateDistance<DistanceMethod>>();
    }

     [Fact]
    public void DistanceController_CorrectValue()
    {
        var p1 = new DistancePoint
        {
            Latitude = 55.39291815,
            Longitude = -7.389611015997305
        };

        var p2 = new DistancePoint
        {
            Latitude = 53.3729581,
            Longitude = -6.3624744
        };

   List<ICalculateDistance<DistanceMethod>> _operators = new 
   List<ICalculateDistance<DistanceMethod>>();
            _operators.Add(Cant do this)

        var calculateDistance = new CalculateDistanceService(_operators) 


    }

    I am using this blog as reference aswell:
    https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/strategy-pattern-with-enum-constraints
```

Comment: are you getting any error?, what exactly your problem is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Well, you should write an implementation of `ICalculateDistance` interface with concrete enum type, like `ICalculateDistance<GeodesicCurve>`, and add it to the list